# location of reports in BO server - crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I am new to this field and have no idea how this works. We have BusinessObjects installed on one of our windows servers. We can access the reports after hitting the URL. Now I am trying to make some changes on the reports,  I can open this report from **Crystal Report > Open > Enterprise > local**

I checked Web Content under BO installation path, FileStore but I am not able to find out what is the location of this **Enterprise**. Can someone tell where we can find these reports on our windows server?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the filestore (FRS) is located in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\FileStore

However, it is very rare that you'd need to access files in the FRS directly.  If you do, you'll need to know the exact folder path and file name.  In BI launchpad, open up the report's properties, and the path will be displayed as "File Name".  This is the logical path relative to the FRS parent.

Comment: I couldn't find the path for those reports. In order to make any changes, I can make the changes to those using CrystalReport and save it desktop. to make these changes available to end-user do I need to publish them?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have made your changes to the report you need to save it back to the BusinessObjects platform. If you are using **Crystal Reports for Enterprise** here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZc33NDJzYc) on how to do that. If you are using **Crystal Reports 201x** check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjvLHr-JuZA).